# pickle files dumped from fbprophet trained models in linux environment are larger than windows

Tags: python-3.x, linux, windows, facebook-prophet, pystan

I am using python 3.6 in both windows & Linux environments. I could not run the prophet model on Linux with pystan 2.18.1.0 on Linux but I can only run it on windows with that version. I am saving the trained model to Pickle files. Can anyone help me answer why the pickle file sizes are 10.x larger in Linux than windows?. I thought it might be a compiler issue and upgraded my GCC compiler on Linux server but still not cracked.

Environment details:
Windows:
pystan 2.18.1.0
python3.6
fbprophet 0.6

Linux:
pystan 2.19.1.1
python3.6
fbprophet 0.6